# Azure Event Hub "Event Capture" encryption

Tags: azure-eventhub

The "Event Capture" feature in Azure Event Hubs pipes event data to an Azure data store such as Azure BLOB Storage or an Azure Data Lake. When configured to do this, will Event Capture *encrypt* the data in transit to the storage location?

I can find information online in Microsoft's Azure doco that indicates encryption at rest can be achieved (both in storage and in the message stores within Azure Event Hubs) however I am unclear as to whether data in transit is also encrypted. Anyone know if this is the case or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My assumption is Azure Event Hub and Azure Storage will talk to each other via HTTPS protocol which ensures secure communication i.e. encryption in transit.

You can enforce this encryption in transit further by enabling [Secure transfer required](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/storage/common/storage-require-secure-transfer). This will make sure all clients (in this case Azure Event Hub) use HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks -- this answers it!